# Oracle sql capitalized turkish characters

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, capitalize

Hello In my table I have a string like that `TAKIM ELBİSE FABRİKASI`
I want to capitalize it with `INITCAP()` but it returns like `Takim Elbise Fabrikasi` but My expected result is `Takım Elbise Fabrikası` how can I do it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know Turkish, but - try

```
NLS_INITCAP('TAKIM ELBİSE FABRİKASI')
```

or

```
NLS_INITCAP('TAKIM ELBİSE FABRİKASI', 'nls_sort = xturkish')
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried and returns like  Takim Elbise Fabrikasi again. In turkish chars I should return ı İ should return i.

Comment: Hm, too bad :( I hoped that **NLS_**INITCAP would help. Sadly, it doesn't. If you wait a little bit longer, I know that people from Turkey visit this site (such as @Barbaros Ozhan) so - perhaps they'll be able to assist.

Comment: I solved it with xturkish rather than turkish. NLS_INITCAP helped me a lot to find correct solution thanks. If you updated with xturkish this answer may help anotheres who need in the future

Comment: Ah, right! Stupid me, should have been more careful. Sorry & thank you. I'm glad you made it work.

Answer (score 1):

In the data, only the first letter of the words was capitalized and the others were lowercased, while all capital I letters in Turkish were translated as i. No matter what I did, it didn't work, but thanks to 'nls_sort = xturkish', I can draw it as a lowercase I.

Thanks to NLS_INITCAP(K.ADI, 'nls_sort = xturkish'), the word "CANLI" appears as "Canlı".

I also used it to print in uppercase letters.

UPPER(NLS_UPPER(S.BASLIK, 'nls_sort = xturkish'))

Thanks